# Java - Can't I put a arraylist inside of a list of lists - how to get around?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have some function that I am given. I cannot change the parameters of the function of the types of the arguments. My question is about the argument "synonyms" below:

```
public List<String> generateSentences(List<List<String>> synonyms, String text) {
            
     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> synTotal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(Arrays.asList("hi"));
    
      synTotal.add(synonyms.get(0));
```

I create this ArrayList of Arraylist of strings, synTotal, and put data in it. However, when I try to add to this created list of lists, I get the following error:

[image]

I am pretty confused. My understanding of lists is that lists are objects, and arraylists are implementation of objects. But that a list always needs to be created with a proper implementation (arraylist/linked list/etc).

So based on that Idea, I would have thought that the argument List<List> must have been implemented somehow as one of these special implementations. If not, how do I give an implementation to a List<List> if it's already instantiated in the argument?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` for `synTotal`, use `List<List<String>>`. Initialize it using the diamond operator: `new ArrayList<>(...)`.

Comment: "My understanding of lists is that lists are objects, and arraylists are implementation of objects" `List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is an implementation of the _interface_

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> synTotal = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Do this instead:
`List<List<String>> synTotal = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Because when you create a `List<> variable`, you use `new ArrayList<>`, but the variable must be used as a `List<>`, because the type of the variable is a `List<>`.